# L'uso transitivo del verbo "scherzare"?

Tags: verbs, regional

Il verbo *scherzare* [è intransitivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scherzare/) e quindi non prevede nessun altro argomento oltre al soggetto, oppure prevede un secondo argomento introdotto dalle preposizioni: *il gatto scherza con il rocchetto*.

Il [*Dizionario moderno*](https://archive.org/stream/dizionariomodern00panzuoft#page/436/mode/2up) di Panzini (1905) registra l'uso transitivo dialettale:

> **Scherzare:** usano a Milano questo verbo transitivamente: *scherzare uno* nel senso di *farsi giuoco* o *beffe* di qualcuno, *minchionare, canzonare*, e non solo nel dialetto, ma altresi nel linguaggio familiare: idiotismo a cui non è facile sottrarsi; comunissimo, ad es., nelle scuole.

Ma la canzone di Elio e le storie tese ["John Holmes"](http://www.testitradotti.it/canzoni/elio-e-le-storie-tese/john-holmes) inizia con

> Quand’ero piccolo, tutti mi scherzavano...

Inoltre, nel romanzo *D'amore e d'odio* di Maria Rosa Cutrufelli
(Frassinelli, 2008) si legge

> Prima di tagliarle, però, il signor Colajanni volle mettermi in posa: "Per ricordare il punto di partenza", mi scherzò al momento dello scatto.

Ormai diventa comune l'uso transitivo? Oppure esiste un contesto particolare dove si usa *scherzare qlc.*?

Comment: Non so la Cutrufelli, ma il linguaggio delle canzoni di Elio e c. non lo definirei sempre “uso comune”... :-) (E, più seriamente, gli Elii sono milanesi, coerentemente con l'uso regionale registrato a suo tempo da Panzini.)

Comment: Io sono italiano, non di Milano e non ho mai sentito questo uso del verbo scherzare...

Comment: Pure io sono di Milano. Scherzare è usato transitivamente in contesto... scherzoso.

Comment: Pur se incorretta la forma transitiva di scherzare viene comunemente usata nell'alta Lombardia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mai sentito usare il verso 'scherzare' transitivamente, né a Milano né altrove. Eviterei e non raccomanderei di usarlo.

A riguardo può essere d'aiuto questo estratto dall'Accademia della Crusca.

[Scherzare](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/valenze-reggenze-verbi):

> - Il verbo **scherzare è comunemente usato nella forma intransitiva** con il significato di ‘comportarsi in modo leggero e divertito, fare scherzi, prendersi gioco di qualcuno’ e, in questa accezione, può essere monovalente e quindi non prevedere nessun altro argomento oltre al soggetto (“i ragazzi hanno scherzato tutto il pomeriggio”), oppure prevedere un secondo argomento introdotto dalle preposizioni con (“scherzare con qualcuno”) e su (“scherzare su qualcosa”).
> - **Esiste anche un uso transitivo, raro e di 
>     provenienza lombarda**, con significato di ‘deridere, beffare, canzonare, prendere in giro’ attestato già da Panzini nel suo Dizionario moderno (1905), dove si legge: «Nel parlar familiare (Piemonte, Lombardia) questo verbo è usato transitivamente nel senso di schernire, minchionare, canzonare, “I compagni mi scherzano”». **L’uso transitivo del verbo scherzare trova quindi le sue origini nei dialetti di area nord-occidentale e risulta prevalente nei registri familiare e nell’uso giovanile; anche le attestazioni d’autore vanno nella direzione di tale provenienza con esempi da Pavese e Fenoglio, con qualche estensione anche in autori di altre aree (come ad esempio Cardarelli).** Presente anche nelle scelte linguistiche della scrittrice milanese Anna Radius Zuccari, in arte Neera che, nel suo Il marito dell’amica (Libreria Editrice Galli, 1891), scrive: “Nel momento che un fanciullo già grandicello, passandole accanto, la scherzò sulla sua pelle scura e sull’abito dimesso” (p. 81). Pressoché tutti i principali vocabolari dell’uso contemporanei contemplano la forma transitiva del verbo, alcuni (come Devoto-Oli e Sabatini-Coletti) marcandolo come dialettale, altri (come il GRADIT e lo ZINGARELLI) segnalandone il basso uso.
> - Sta di fatto che, anche nella lingua contemporanea, l’uso transitivo compare, talvolta con intenti mimetici (come nel caso del romanzo di Ernesto Ferrero, L’anno dell’indiano, Einaudi, 2001, in cui, a p. 194, si legge: “l’avvocato lo scherzò affettuosamente: Ecco il nostro ribelle!”), oppure con chiare finalità ironiche e scherzose, come nella canzone di Elio e le storie tese, John Holmes che inizia con “quand’ero piccolo, tutti mi scherzavano...”.
> - **Fatti salvi questi particolari contesti, il verbo in italiano è normalmente intransitivo.**

Answer (score 3):

Questo uso transitivo del verbo "scherzare" è riportato dal [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00982.jpg) ed è qualificato come "regionale". Ecco le diverse accezioni e gli esempi letterari che dà questo vocabolario per "scherzare" usato transitivamente (appare tra l'altro la citazione del *Dizionario moderno* di Panzini riprodotta nella domanda):

> **13**.  Tr.  Region.  Deridere,  beffare,  canzonare, prendere in giro. 
>        *Panzini* [1905], IV-436: ‘Scherzare’: usano a Milano que­sto  verbo  transitivamente:  scherzare  uno,  nel  senso  di farsi  giuoco  o  beffe  di  qualcuno,  minchionare,  canzonare, e  non  solo  nel  dialetto,  ma  altresì  nel  linguaggio  familiare; idiotismo  a  cui  non  è  facile  sottrarsi,  comunissimo, ad esempio, nelle  scuole. *Cardarelli*, 181:  Chi  perciò  inten­desse  ‘scherzarmi’,  come  si  dice  in  Lombardia,  potrei  ri­spondere  che  per  avere  un  bel  paio  di  corna  non  è  neces­sario  essere  di  Corneto. 
>   *G. Raimondi*, 6-198:  Un  fattorino lo  scherzava,  dicendogli  in  dialetto:  «Ma  guarda,  ‘cagnen’, che  hai  perduto  le gambe». *Pavese*, 1-113:  Solo  Talino 
>   aveva  il  muso  come  me;  sembrava  che  sapesse  qualcosa; ma Vinverra  era  allegro  e  ci  scherzava  tutti  due. *Fenoglio*,
>   1-1-1286:  Gli  ufficiali,  i  colleghi,  ti  scherzano  e  ti  punzec­chiano in mille modi.
>   
>       – Trascurare,  prendere  alla  leggera  un  compito 
>   o un impegno.
>        *Fenoglio*, 1-1-1640:  Mancano  dieci  minuti  e  li  facciamo fino  all’ultimo.  Noi  partigiani  la  guardia  la  scherziamo troppo. 
>        – Nel  calcio,  superare  un  avversario  con  una 
>   finta che lo sorprenda e lo confonda.
>       
>   *Il  Giorno* [19-1-1959]:  Parte  Ghiggia  scherzando  Castel­letti in dribbling.

Answer (score -1):

No, l'uso della forma transitiva del verbo scherzare è incorretta.
Si può solo in casi di licenze poetiche oppure, come nel caso di Elio e le storie tese, volutamente  ironici e comici.